# AF-XDP: Is there a bug regarding small packets?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, xdp-bpf

Is there a known (or maybe unknown) bug regarding the size of packets in the AF-XDP socket framework (+ libbpf)?

I am experiencing a strange packet loss for my application:

- IPv4/UDP/RTP packet stream with all packets being the same size (1442 bytes): no packet loss
- IPv4/UDP/RTP packet stream where pretty much all packets are the same size (1492 bytes) except a special "marker" packet (only 357 bytes but they are also IPv4/UDP-packets): all marker packets get lost

I added a `bpf_printk` statement in my XDP-Kernelprogram:

```
const int len = bpf_ntohs(iph->tot_len);
if(len < 400) {
    bpf_printk("FOUND PACKET LEN < 400: %d.\n", len);
}
```

This output is never observed via `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`. So these small RTP-marker packets aren't even received by my kernel filter - no wonder why I don't receive them in userspace.

`ethtool -S <if>` shows me this number: `rx_256_to_511_bytes_phy`. This number is increasing in a similar rate as marker-packets should come in (about 30/s). So this means that my NIC does receive the packets but my XDP-program doesn't - why?

Any idea what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: No idea :/. I suppose your `bpf_printk()` works without the check on size for the longer packets? If you feel like this is related to length, you could try to send packets of different sizes (e.g. with netcat) to see if you can pin down the size limit, or if packets differing only in size are effectively treated the same... That's all I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Yes, `bpf_printk()` works the other way around (packets larger than 400 bytes). Your idea with `netcat` is a good one. I'll try that

Comment: I get `Connection refused` using `nping` in case `--data-length` is less than `372` @Qeole

Comment: Are you able to receive small packets with a "normal" XDP program (i.e., no AF_XDP)? What NIC and driver are you using?

Comment: @pchaigno I was purely my mistake. I am too dump to do pointer arithmetic: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/issues/116#issuecomment-607128228

Answer (score 0):

First, `bpf_printk()` doesn't always work for me. You may want to take a look at this snippet (kernel-space code):

```c
// Nicer way to call bpf_trace_printk()
#define bpf_custom_printk(fmt, ...)                     \
        ({                                              \
            char ____fmt[] = fmt;                       \
            bpf_trace_printk(____fmt, sizeof(____fmt),  \
                    ##__VA_ARGS__);                     \
        })

// print:
bpf_custom_printk("This year is %d\n", 2020);
// output: sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe
```

Second: May be the packet entered the other NIC queue. You may want to use vanilla code from [xdp-tutorial](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/advanced03-AF_XDP) and add the kernel tracing from the above snippet to print size of packet, then compile and run the example program with `-q 1` for queue number 1 for example.

A way to get size of packet:

```c
void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
size_t size_pkt = data - data_end;
bpf_custom_printk("Packet size %d\n", size_pkt);
```

Comment: My Macro definition of `bpf_printk` is the exact same as yours, it is just named differently. Please stop replying to my questions